# AJAX problem in CiviCase - Administer Case Types

Tags: civicase, ajax

I'm getting the same effect as reported [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=36039.0). I'm trying to set up CiviCase, and all seems fine except when I try to Administer->CiviCase->Case Types I just get blank screen.
The JavaScript console shows a series of errors as shown below. I've been through all the standard trouble-shooting things, and am stumped now.

Joomla 3.3.6, CiviCrm 4.6.5

Any ideas much appreciated. Thanks.

Javascript console output:

option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/a/:109 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected

?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=0KJad:5 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'userFramework' of undefined
(anonymous function)    @   ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=0KJad:5
(anonymous function)    @   ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US&r=0KJad:5

?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=0KJad:11 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'modules' of undefined(anonymous function) @ ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=0KJad:11(anonymous function) @ ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/angular-modules&format=js&r=0KJad:19

?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/menujs/2/en_US/1/oQmyf7Hm:110 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'resourceBase' of undefined(anonymous function) @ ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/menujs/2/en_US/1/oQmyf7Hm:110(anonymous function) @ ?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/ajax/menujs/2/en_US/1/oQmyf7Hm:111

angular.js:38
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.17/$injector/modulerr?p0=crmApp&p1=Error%3A…vicrm%2Fbower_components%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3Fr%3D0KJad%3A17%3A381)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:38(anonymous function) @ angular.js:4154q @ angular.js:326g @ angular.js:4115bb @ angular.js:4041d @ angular.js:1455xc @ angular.js:1476Od @ angular.js:1370(anonymous function) @ angular.js:26438m.Callbacks.j @ jquery.js:3148m.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.js:3260m.extend.ready @ jquery.js:3472J @ jquery.js:3503

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but others with a similar problem should check out https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25781/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. It was the same issue as reported [here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16416). It wasn't a CiviCRM problem at all. The JavaScript errors were caused by the K2 component, which alters the HTML output after CiviCRM does. K2 was passing text containing quotes (specifically 'prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"') to JavaScript, so these quotes ended up unescaped. More info [here](http://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/41292-system-plugin-shouldn-t-modify-html-tag-on-adminstrator). The solution was to apply [this patch](https://github.com/joomlaworks/k2/commit/f5cea21896647bf5be0cbe7ee9498272f298b27c) to K2 (or, in my case, to remove K2 altogether, since we decided not to use it).