# Contributions page - Endless Loop and Doubling Content - JS problem?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, ajax

we have trouble with our civicrm contribution page since we updated to 5.16.3 (running in wordpress 5.2.4):

the contributions page was running fine with paypal standard and a pay later option in the same wordpress with an outdated civi. After the update we suddenly have the following issue:

> **1.** after filling in the profile and amount (and i have built a new profile to include as well as a complete new contributions page to check if the trouble was with this part of the page - which it wasn't) i check "PayPal" and confirm my contribution -> **i am thrown to the same form** again (without the fields filled in) **but the URL is** ?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/contribute/transact&qf_Confirm_display=true&qfKey=......
>
> **2.** after filling in the profile and amount and using "pay later" **before** clicking on "confirm" the form suddenly doubles - with all the text and fields which the original form has...I then cannot click "confirm", or if I fill out everything (double) it just throws me back at the same page.
>
> **3.** my Console gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' with the page
> /?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fl10n-js%2Fen_US&cid=13&r=QZKnC
> (when checking [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5084/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-error-on-l10n-js-files) this doesn't really describe the issue, as it is the same for logged-in and logged-out users....doesn't make a difference for me)
> we manually changed languages with this civi installation, as I feared it might be the German language files which cause this issue, but the en_US files produce the same issue...

The Site we are talking about (our beta-test site) is: https://ls-beta.de/spenden

-> anyone any ideas what the problem could be?
-> help is deeply appreciated

thx!

Comment: The answer in the question you linked is the same regardless of whether it happens logged in or out.  If you have a WordPress plugin or theme that's improperly injecting HTML on every page load, it needs to be found and fixed.  If you give a link to the page itself, folks may be able to help more.

Comment: Dear Jon,
thx - i am just curious, because I didn't change anything in the code, and it worked before and now it doesn't...
but the page we're looking at is this (our beta-test-site):
[link](https://ls-beta.de/spenden/)

Comment: this might be better on https://chat.civicrm.org.  Civi generates a JavaScript file for l10n on the fly.  Compare the contents of [this link](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/ajax/l10n-js/en_US?cid=203&r=cvN2A) from a Civi demo site with the contents of [this link](https://ls-beta.de/spenden/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fl10n-js%2Fen_US&cid=&r=wEBh4) on your site.  On your site, you don't get the JS file, you're redirected to an HTML page.  This suggests that some configuration - maybe your Apache/nginx settings, maybe a WP theme - is blocking or redirecting this URL.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot Jon - we spent the last days trying to figure it out, but couldn't find it yet....
I'll report if we will be able to solve it....thx anyways for pointing us the right direction